# How to get the position of checked radio button in table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the position of the checked table header without using unique id or value for these radio buttons. How can I do this?

```js
$("#save").on('click', (function() {
  alert();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> A
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> B
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> C
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 </td>
    <td>row 1 </td>
    <td>row 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by 'position' you mean the index of the `th` element that contains the checked radio input, you can find it by using `:has(input:checked)`, then getting its `index()`, like this:

```js
$("#save").on('click', (function() {
  var index = $('th:has(input:checked)').index();
  console.log(index);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> A
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> B
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="header" />
      <br /> C
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 </td>
    <td>row 1 </td>
    <td>row 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```